# How do I keep a TeamViewer session open?

Tags: connection, teamviewer

After a while of having a TeamViewer session open, I get a messagebox up thanking me for using it. And I have to make the connection again.

I am using TeamViewer 13.2

I have seen an option in

> Extras.. Options

where there's a dial I can turn to off

[image]

But I had that set to off and it still disconnected it after a period of time, certainly by the next day it was disconnected, perhaps sooner than that.

Comment: if you go https://www.teamviewer.com/en/support/contact/  it has a telephone number for support , and their recommendation is that that that kind of message , thanking you for using (the free version?) teamviewer, is because "trial license expired""  And so now it thinks i'm using it for commercial use.

Comment: So I have to go to google and search for trial license expired teamviewer, which brings up the link https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Why-do-I-see-TeamViewer-trial-Your-trial-period-has-expired/ta-p/5267  "Why do I see TeamViewer trial - 'Your trial period has expired' ? "  And from there the last line is "Please use this form for the TeamViewer Personal Use Verification to request this."   So go https://www.teamviewer.com/en/support/personal-use-verification/

Comment: And in teamviewer go to extra..open log files.  And get the path to the latest log file. And send it and in the form say  "I am using it for personal use", and they will look into it and email you back making a change so you're set to use it for personal use. So that may solve it, will see

Comment: There are lots of reasons for a connection to drop - not just that the software is enforcing a disconnect... Is your internet connection between the two points 100% stable over this time period?

Comment: @Attie  clearly teamviewer disconnected it , as  I said, I got a message thanking me for using it. That's not something one would see if I was connected outside of teamviewer.  The teamviewer software isn't likely to catch an exception for a disconnection and say "thank you for using our software".

Comment: @barlop thats incorrect.  I use TV and that message pops up whenever the connection is lost unexpectedly.  I got it the other day when connected from my phone to my house when the signal dropped.

Comment: @Keltari hah, ok,  teamviewer is programmed in a silly funny way then. Nevertheless, the guy from teamviewer on the phone, said (based on the info I gave him here and no more), that i'm getting the message because  the trial must have run out and that happens once the trial runs out. So there is that standard cause from teamviewer itself even when the connection timing out is set to off. And they're going to set my version to personal use so then they think it should work, so they should be emaling me